# How to load all test resources without using names in Android?

Tags: android, testing, instrumented-test

In my `androidTest/resources` directory I have a few hundreds of images. I want to read all of them in a loop and test against specific function. I don't want to use their names, as often I don't know them. Is there any possibility to load by regex or iterate through the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Change the name of directory from `resources` to `assets` and then use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.resources.assets.list("")`